# _MACOSX folder in Magento directory

Tags: folder, directory

An old webshop of ours has a _MACOSX folder in its directory. When I backup the webshop it takes a very long time to backup _MACOSX folder. Probally because it is a whole copy of the files in the directory.

Is this folder usefull? Or has this folder been created by someone who uploaded the site from a Apple computer?

If not usefull can it just be deleted?

Comment: "Or has this folder been created by someone who uploaded the site from a Apple computer?" - yes, and you can delete it

Comment: Do you have any idea if this would effect performance of the webshop? If so I will have to check al of our other webshops.

Comment: Unused files do not affect the performance, I'd rather worry about the possibility of information leaking. Make sure that _MACOSX is not publicly accessible, for example with a .htaccess rule

Comment: Oke then I am deleting the folder. Thanks for your information.